# Safari gives padding on top and bottom of SVG logo

Tags: css, svg

I made a logo in svg and implemented it on my website. It works well in all browsers EXCEPT safari

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CVjp/)

NOTE - you muse use safari to recreate my issue. Viewing the fiddle in any other browser shows it like its suppose to be.

Here is my html for the navbar

```
  <div class="navsection">
    <div class="w-nav navbar" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-contain="1">
      <div class="w-container">
        <a class="w-nav-brand" href="#">
          <img class="logo" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/JA_logo_2014_svg.svg"  width="100">
        </a>
        <nav class="w-nav-menu mobilenavmenu" role="navigation"><a class="w-nav-link navlinks" href="#work">work</a><a class="w-nav-link navlinks" href="#contact">contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="w-nav-button">
          <div class="w-icon-nav-menu hamburger"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can get started with

```
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" in your svg header
```

but I cant verify this without your svg on the fiddle

Your css

```
    img {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
        }
    .w-nav-brand {
         display: inline-block;
         position: relative;
         width: 50%;
         padding-bottom: 60%;
        }
```

The 60% needs tuning depending on size and width.

I've used [this guide](http://soqr.fr/testsvg/embed-svg-liquid-layout-responsive-web-design.php) a lot, to good effect, but more with the object tag than img.
Try to trim the amount of css included in your fiddle, you'll get more interest!